# Problem in Criteria with Inner Join

Tags: hibernate

I am running a criteia with following code..

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(BasicTransaction.class);

c.createCriteria("basicTransactionType","basicTransactionType", CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN);

//c.setFetchMode("basicTransactionType", FetchMode.JOIN);

 c.add(Restrictions.and(Restrictions.in("id", l),
            Restrictions.eq("isCommon", true)));

return c.list();
```

where "basicTransactionType" is `enum`

This works fine with `FetchMode.JOIN` but not with  `CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN`

If anyone can explain ?

Comment: Would you mind letting us see the SQL generated by Hibernate and the relevant parts of the data in the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FetchMode.JOIN` provides an outer join while `CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN` specifies an inner join. This might have something to do with the problem.

Comment: I know that FetchMode.JOIN provides an outer join while CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN specifies an inner join.

Comment: This might have something to do with the problem. That's why i have asked the question that why it is not working with Inner Join. Pls help

Comment: @Hardik Mishra - If outer join works and inner join doesn't it suggests that the join columns do not match. That's what I would look into.